# MIPS exceptions what do they mean

Tags: exception, assembly, interrupt, qtspim

I've been studying assembly lately and i can't seem to understand how the exceptions work exactly. More specific, i get the message Exception 6 occurred and ignored. Can someone please explain what exactly does this mean? I am using qtspim.

Comment: After a few seconds of googling, it looks like this is a simulator (spim) thing to help you out, the few I saw off hand are things that real hardware would/should just hang on.  Unaligned accesses, fetching instructions outside that address space, etc.  You have a bug in your code basically, look for it.  I dont know enough about spim to know if it tells you where this occurred (what instruction or address, etc) likewise is there a feature to halt/hang/crash at the fail point rather than ignore and try to continue?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions may be caused by hardware or software. An exception is like an unscheduled function call that jumps to a new address. 
The program may encounter an error condition such as 
an undefined instruction. The program then jumps to code in the operating system (OS), which may choose to terminate the program. Other causes of exceptions are division by zero, attempts to read some nonexistent memory, hardware malfunctions, debugger breakpoints, and arithmetic overflow.

The processor records the cause of an exception and the value of the `PC` 
at the time the exception occurs. It then jumps to the exception handler function. The exception handler is code (usually in the OS) that examines the 
cause of the exception and responds appropriately, It then returns to the program that 
was executing before the exception took place.

In MIPS, the exception handler is always located at `0x80000180`. When an exception occurs, the processor always jumps to this instruction address, regardless of the cause.

The MIPS architecture uses a special-purpose register, called the *Cause* 
register, to record the cause of the exception.

MIPS uses another special-purpose register called the **Exception 
Program Counter** (`EPC`) to store the value of the `PC` at the time an 
exception takes place. The processor returns to the address in `EPC` after 
handling the exception. This is analogous to using `$ra` to store the old 
value of the PC during a `jal` instruction.